# Is there any way to find Time taken for features in Deployment manager to get available on Terraform?

Tags: terraform, deployment-manager

Can you please help me on getting more info about time to get all features of deployment manager available on terraform?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform providers is maintained by the community. The best you can do is to create an issue in the [GitHub repo for Terraform Google provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google) and perhaps a PullRequest with an implementation.